# Prove that $G=\lbrace a+b\sqrt{2}\rbrace$ is isomorphic to $G′=\lbrace\begin{bmatrix}a&2b\\ b&a\end{bmatrix}∣a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\rbrace$

Tags: group-theory

> Consider the following two groups: $G=\{a+b\sqrt{2}\:|\:a,b \in\mathbb{Q}\}$ under addition (a subgroup of the real numbers) and $G'=\{\begin{bmatrix}a&2b\\ b&a\end{bmatrix}|a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ under matric addition. Prove that $G$ and $G'$ are isomorphic.

I'm trying to do this proof, but I have no clue. I know that I'm going to need a $\phi(x)$, or -in this case- a $\phi(a,b)$.  I tried $\phi(a,b) = \begin{bmatrix}a&2b\\ b&a\end{bmatrix}$ and I need to show that it is one to one, or $\phi(a,b) = \phi(c,d) \Rightarrow (a,b) = (c,d)$ (I think, for one var. it's $\phi(x) = \phi(y) \Rightarrow x = y$).

Show onto show that $\phi(a,b) = (c,d)$ where $(a,b) \in \mathbb{G}$, 
and show that it preserves the operation $\phi(a+c,b+d) = \phi(a,b) + \phi(c,d)$

Comment: @geppetto Please do **not** edit nice, specific titles into generic garbage.

Comment: @Lord_Farin, sorry, but my edit happened before yours.. I didn't see yours.. Do you understand? I mean you haven't to be rude ;)

Comment: @nullgeppetto I noticed, but I wanted to make it *very* clear that your title edit was *bad*. When the edit was performed is irrelevant to my point. What exactly made you choose "Q: Isomorphic groups with matrix" as a title in the first place?

Comment: @Lord_Farin I don't think that the title you mentioned was my choice... really.

Comment: [Yes it was](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/575646/revisions) (revision 4). That OP had used this title before (due to their unawareness of MathJax functionality in the title, I presume) is immaterial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the map
$$\phi:G\to G', \\ \;\;\;\;\;\;a+b\sqrt{2}\mapsto \begin{bmatrix}a&2b\\ b&a\end{bmatrix}$$
Then $\phi$ is a group homomorphism, since (note that both structures are groups under addition)
$$\phi\left( (a_1+b_1\sqrt{2})+(a_2+b_2\sqrt{2})\right)=\phi\left( (a_1+a_2)+(b_1+b_2)\sqrt{2})\right)=\begin{bmatrix}a_1+a_2&2(b_1+b_2)\\ b_1+b_2&a_1+a_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a_1&2b_1\\ b_1&a_1\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}a_2&2b_2\\ b_2&a_2\end{bmatrix}=\phi(a_1+b_1\sqrt{2})+\phi(a_2+b_2\sqrt{2}).$$
Now you only need to prove that this map is bijective, i.e both injective and surjective. I will leave this as an (easy) exercise to you.

Answer (score 3):

Matthew,

To show that two groups are isomorphic, you can produce a group homomorphism which is both surjective and injective. More precisely, you need a map $\varphi:G\to G'$ such that for all $x,y\in G$ you have $\varphi(xy)=\varphi(x)\varphi(y)$, and is bijective.

You do not want a multivariable function $\varphi(a,b)$ as you mentioned. From your question, it seems that you might want to read about group homomorphisms more carefully before trying to go about solving this problem.

As for the map $\varphi:G\to G'$ it helps to note that $G$ is generated as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space by $1$ and $\sqrt{2}$. This makes the problem easier because you can define $\varphi$ on 1 and $\sqrt{2}$, then extend it by linearity to all of $G$.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Opening the homomorphism chapter now!

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\End}{\mathrm{End}}\renewcommand{\phi}{\varphi}\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbf{Q}}\newcommand{\R}{\mathbf{R}}$This is another take at the excellent solution provided by **@user121314**.

Consider an arbitrary commutative ring $A$ with unity. Let $\End(A)$ be the ring of endomorphisms of $A$ *regarded as an abelian group*.

Consider the map $\phi : A \to \End(A)$ given by
\begin{equation*}
a \mapsto (x \mapsto a x).
\end{equation*}
It is easy to see $\phi(a) : x \mapsto a x$ is indeed an element of $\End(A)$, and that $\phi$ is a ring homorphism. Moreover if $\phi(a) = \phi(b)$, then their values on $1$ are the same, so $a = b$. It follows that $\phi$ is injective.

Now consider $A = \Q[\sqrt{2}] = \{ a_{0} + a_{1} \sqrt{2} : a_{0}, a_{1} \in \Q \}$. This is not only a ring, but also a vector space over $\Q$, with basis $1, \sqrt{2}$. And each $\phi(a): A \to A$ is clearly a linear map. If you write $\phi(a)$, for $a =  a_{0} + a_{1} \sqrt{2}$ as a matrix with respect to the basis $1, \sqrt{2}$, you have
\begin{equation*}
\phi(a)(1) = a = a_{0} + a_{1} \sqrt{2}, 
\qquad
\phi(a)(\sqrt{2}) = a \sqrt{2} = 2 a_{1} + a_{0} \sqrt{2}.
\end{equation*}
Hence the matrix of $\phi(a)$ is
\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{0} & 2 a_{1}\\
a_{1} & a_{0}
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation*}

So this explains why one uses that particular matrix. I recommend you to try out other rings $A$, like $A = \Q[\sqrt{3}]$, or $A = \R[i]$ (that's the complex numbers, of course)